# AngularJS with Restful Java & MySQL

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I use AngularJS with RESTful WebService using MySQL database. I get data into database from view page. But my problem is - I can't sum in function. Please help me...

Table+JAR:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMLoT.jpg)

View+web+Bean+Controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53p8.jpg)

Comment: copy past the code here not the screen shots.

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `currentAssetsData` is an array. So, you have to modify your calculation syntax like this.

```
$scope.currentAssetsData['cash_hand'] + $scope.currentAssetsData['bank_account']
```

Then you need to return the result in function :

```
$scope.currentAssetSum = function(){
  return $scope.currentAssetsData['cash_hand'] + $scope.currentAssetsData['bank_account'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return** the values in your function:

```
$scope.currentAssetSum = function(){
  return $scope.currentAssetsData.cash_hand + $scope.currentAssetsData.bank_account;
}
```

Comment: and exactly which part it doesn't work? Whats the cause? Is the `$http` request even successful? Does the `response.data` contain the values you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should put return statement inside the function like this.

```
$scope.currentAssetSum = function (){
    return $scope.currentAssetsData.cash_hand+$scope.scope.currentAssetsData.bank_account;
}
```